# How would I go about making a total in php?

Tags: php

[image]

```
  <?php
    $name = $_POST['FName'];
    $Lasname = $_POST['LName'];
    $NUMSTREET = $_POST['NumStreet'];
    $city = $_POST['City'];
    $STATE = $_POST['State'];
    $zip = $_POST['ZipCode'];
    $checkin = $_POST['Check-in'];
    $checkout = $_POST['Check-out'];
    $TotPeople = $_POST['NumberPeople'];
    $ROOM = $_POST['RoomType'];
    $Tele = $_POST['Phone'];
`$EMAIL = $_POST['Email'];`
    $PAY = $_POST['Payment'];
    $cardnumber = $_POST['CardNum'];
    $SpecialReq = $_POST['reqmsg'];
    $current_date = strtotime($checkin);
    $date_out = strtotime($checkout);
    $NUMDAYS = $date_out - $current_date;
    $king = intval(200);
    $queen = intval(150);
    $suite = intval(300);
    $total_Charge;
    ?>
```

I need to calculate a total where it multiples the total people by the room they are booking (king Room = $200 Queen Room = $150 and a Suite = $300 also the tax is 7%). I need it to calculate a total charge and echo that. Im Just caught up on how to assign the values to said room and multiple it by the total people. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I would make the room types an array, like this, you can add as many as you like to this array in the future:

```
$roomTypes = array(
    'king' => 200,
    'queen' => 150,
    'suite' => 300
);
```

Then calculate like this:

```
$totalPeople = 2;
$room = 'King';
$totalCharge = ($totalPeople * $roomTypes[strtolower($room)]) * 1.07;
echo $totalCharge; //428.0
```

PS: Try and keep your variable naming consistent :)

Comment: Thank you, Yea I'm still learning atm. I just had trouble with this part. Thank you again

Comment: No problem, please upvote and accept my answer if it helped you.